# Value goes up by 2 instead of 1, also some array error's i don't understand

Tags: php

So i have this problem i can't figure out. but what the problem is that when i press the right arrow in the page, the value has to go up by 1, not 2. and when pressed the left button, it should go -1 and that works normally.

i try to get all the id's from the database and put it in a array. the functions check the array for end and first values and put's the data to the page input.

here is the code where i struggle with:

```
    // checks if the variable has not been set, otherwise errors and problems will occur
if (empty($_SESSION["huidigeklant"])) {setHuidigeKlant();}


// common variables set to use
$id[] = $_SESSION["id"];

// makes a pre connection to check if a value can be set up or down to prevent errors in the input page.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from klanten"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    array_push($id, $row["id"]);
}

// checks first and last array value of the session id
function checkfirstklant(){ $firstID = reset($id); return $firstID; }
function checklastklant(){ $lastID = end($id); return $lastID; }


// checks first if the right or left button has been pressed and checks after that if the value is already at the first or end array
if (isset($_POST['leftbutton'])){
    if (($firstID = checkfirstklant()) != $_SESSION["huidigeklant"]) {
        $_SESSION['huidigeklant']--;
        echo "huidige klant = " . $_SESSION["huidigeklant"];
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['rightbutton'])){
    if (($lastID = checklastklant()) != $_SESSION["huidigeklant"]) {
        $_SESSION['huidigeklant']++;
        echo "huidige klant = " . $_SESSION["huidigeklant"];
    }
}
```

one thing to mention and already figured that out. the "setHuidigeKlant() sets $_SESSION["huidigeklant"] to 1".

so my question is: How can i prevent the program to set the value to 1, but still set the value to 1 if it hasn't been set in the first place?

i coudln't find a specific answer for this, but if you do. send a link to it please

thanks in advance ;)

Comment: _“but still set the value to 1 if it hasn't been set in the first place?”_ - use `isset` …?

Comment: You are already only calling `setHuidigeKlant()` if the session value is empty. A more interesting question, are you actually calling `session_start()` before doing all of the above?

Comment: session_start is at the top of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["huidigeklant"])) { $_SESSION["huidigeklant"] = 1;}
```

Comment: OF COURSE! why haven't i though of that?! GENIUS THAT YOU ARE.

Answer (score 1):

So i already found my problem xD

what Difster already said at the post above, i need to isset my $_SESSSION["huidigeklant"] instead of checking if it is empty.

and i have to check if i am already at the end of the variable in the if statement instead of letting that doing by a function.

so now everything works as requested ;)

thanks again